# Meteor: Trying to send data from a dynamic form into a Server-Side Method?

Tags: meteor

I'll try my best to explain what my problem is - I would write it up in meteorpad but I think its either down or deleted :/

I have a form that takes a name and phone number, the phone number field is dynamic, so the user can add multiple phone numbers before submitting the form.
When the form is submitted the 'name' field is sent to the server with:

```
name = event.target.name.value; 
Meteor.call("insertDetails", name);
```

And then in the server:

```
Meteor.methods({ 
insertDetails: function (name) { 
  Database.insert({ 
  name: name ...
  })

 Email.send({ text: "Hi " + name + " your phone numbers listed are " + ????
```

How would I do this with the dynamic phone number field, because the user could add 10 phone numbers, i'll need to send them all to the server and be able to use them in the Email.Send..

Comment: we can send multiple parameters to Meteor.call , so why don't you send phonenumbers as another parameter??

Comment: @SaiRam Like I said, the form (specifically the phone field) is dynamic. You can add more than 1 phone number to the collection, they won't be all saved under "phoneNumber", as then you're emailing a bunch of phone numbers back to back. I want each phone number to be separate from one another

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you could do something like:

```
var details= {
    name: event.target.name.value,
    emails: [
        event.target.email1.value,
        event.target.email2.value,
        event.target.email3.value,
        etc.
    ]
}
Meteor.call("insertDetails", details);
```

I'm not sure what kind of email inputs you use, but whatever way you can probably use a for loop or something to store the exact number of email addresses that were entered with less code.

On the server side you would simply have to do this:

```
Meteor.methods({ 
    insertDetails: function (details) { 
        Database.insert(details);
        var emailText = "Hi " + details.name + ", your phone numbers listed are ";
        for (var i = 0; i < details.emails.length; i++){
            emailText += details.emails[i];
            if (i == details.emails.length - 2){
                emailText += " and ";
            } else if (i != details.emails.length - 1){
                emailText += ", ";
            }
        }
        Email.send({to: '',from: '', text: emailText});
    }
});
```

Since you've stored your email addresses in an array on the client side, your method can rely on the length of that array to dynamically change the message that is produced. The two if-statements inside the for loop help formulate punctuation and sentence structure correctly.